# how to know what is the actual width of screen from storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes

I am now sure how place a navigation bar which will fit to the screen width.

here in xcode 6.2

[image: xcode snapshot]

The Home is the navigation bar which is of full width but when I run the application the width is something like this

[image: simulator snapshot]

Here i am not sure how to make the width of the navigation bar to fill the complete width.
Also i am not sure what exactly is the sizeclass do. So i have disabled the size class.
The device i have chosen universal while creating the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you created your navigation by your own - try using Navigation controller.

Regarding your question about size, if you look closely you will see that you are designing for iPhone 4/5, and your simulator uses iPhone 6. What you have to do here is use autolayout constraints, so your views get resized as well.

Here is a link for auto layout: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1